# AS5600 PWM output frequency

Tags: sensor, embedded, position-sensor, as5600

I was reading about ways to get angle measurement using an AS5600, data sheet:

https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/AMS_AS5600_Datasheet_EN.PDF

If I select PWM output I am confused on the maximum angle update rate. According to the datasheet it appears the PWMF maximum is about 900 Hz and the PWM cycles are around 4500 per measurement which would mead it would take over 5 seconds at the fastest speed to measure the position of the device using this method.

What I am reading wrong? It seems like such a slow output would be useless and you should always use I2C?

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, because it certainly *seems* to say that it would take 5 seconds. But that makes no sense to me. Logically I would think that the "PWM clock period" is not the same as the PWM frequency set by those two bits. The 4351 PWM clock periods that make up a single frame are probably tied to the PWM frequency - so if you set the PWM frequency to 900Hz, than a PWM clock period would be equal to 0.255us (900 frames per second, each frame consisting of 4351 periods, -> 1s/(900*4351p) = 2.556E-7 s/p).

And this makes more sense as a PWM signal, the 5 second option is more of just transmitting a bunch of 0s and 1s and I'm not sure why they would refer to that as PWM.

Edit: [here's](https://docs.simplefoc.com/magnetic_sensor_pwm) some sample code with explanations for this sensor that may help

Comment: I’ve used this sensor before and your analysis is correct, the periods refer to subdivisions of the selected PWM period

Comment: So the PWMF setting refers to the frequency of sensor update? IE 900hz means 900 updates a second?

Comment: @FourierFlux sure, you could think of it that way.